# Why every constant expression can be cast to enumeration type

Tags: c++, enums, implicit-conversion

When we're defining enumeration (scoped or unscoped) any enumerator has the type of its enumeration. For instance, consider the following:

```
enum E { z=5 } //This unscoped enumerator has underlying type int implcitly
```

So `const int` can be casts to `E`. Is there a standard conversion?

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks! I've found it into the standard just now. Section 7.2/5 N3797.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a standard conversion?

The standard specifies, at §4.5/3, that:

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not
>   fixed (7.2) **can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the
>   following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration
>   (i.e., the values in the range bmin to bmax as described in 7.2): int,
>   unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned
>   long long int.** If none of the types in that list can represent all the
>   values of the enumeration, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type
>   can be converted to a prvalue of the extended integer type with lowest
>   integer conversion rank (4.13) greater than the rank of long long in
>   which all the values of the enumeration can be represented. If there
>   are two such extended types, the signed one is chosen.

(emphasis mine)

Section §7.2/10 also specifies that an enumerator type can be converted to an integer by integral promotion, but not the other way around:

```
enum color { red, yellow, green=20, blue };
color c = 1; // error: type mismatch
int i = yellow; // OK: yellow converted to integral value 1
```

(example from the standard)

*Note: All quotes are taken from the [N3936 draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/N3936.pdf).*